# proper way to set badge value on uninstantiated view controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have 2 view controllers in a tab bar controller. My 2nd Nav Controller wants to set a badge value.
This controller is not loaded when the app starts, so the badge does not show. If I go over to that tab, the badge is properly updated.

this snippet runs when the tab's View Controller loads/reloads/updates/etc...

[self.navigationController.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",[self.photos count]]];

Is the correct way to do this: Override the Nav Controller with a custom class and put the badge value in at that level? It seems like that is where I should put this info, but I haven't found a definite answer.

Comment: Where is your 2nd _View_ Controller getting it's data from? What is `self.photos`? Is there any way you can get at that same data from your first view controller?

Comment: The 2 view controllers really shouldn't see each other's data. They are dissimilar, self-contained applications. The self.photos information is ultimately coming out of a user's defaults list, but I seem to keep thinking that it would be "bad" to have that 1st view controller grab a piece of data that it shouldn't really know anything about.

Comment: It's not strictly relevant but... are you using storyboard, xib or just code?

Comment: and... just to be clear... you have a UITabBarController, with two items, and each item's initial UIViewController is embedded in a separate UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes, it is in a storyboard and just like you said. UITabBarController going to 2 different UINavigationCollers that have viewcontrollers embedded in each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the TabBarController is loaded, all of it's contained initial viewControllers are initialised. But their *views* are not loaded until you navigate to the respective tab item. So you can't execute code at this point in any of the view-loading methods (`viewDidLoad` etc). However you can execute code by overriding one of the initialisation methods.

If using storyboards the process of unarchiving the viewController triggers this method when the NIB has loaded:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{

}
```

If not using Storyboards, this initialiser is called prior to NIB loading:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

In either case you can override these methods to execute some code...

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self.navigationController.tabBarItem 
           setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"badgeValue"]]];
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.navigationController.tabBarItem 
           setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"badgeValue"]]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

However you will need to take care where you are getting your data from. At this point `self.photos` may be uninitialised for example. If the data for this is coming out of userdefaults, you should be able to read those in here and set your badge accordingly.

Comment: Yes - that is working. Is there a [super awakeFromNib] that needs to be called before executing any of my code?

Comment: @kejoki - yes, I've added a [super awakeFromNib].. in case the `super` is doing something with it.